# Remapping C pointer to a 3D array

Tags: c

I am trying to get a pointer to an array integers to be temporarily remapped in a function later on to save myself pointer math.  I've tried to see if any other questions answered it, but I've been unable to reproduce the methods described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28351093/pointer-to-multidimensional-array-in-c), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14015556/how-to-map-the-indexes-of-a-matrix-to-a-1-dimensional-array-c), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43144857/c-pointer-to-pointer-array).

Fundamentally, I just want to temporally treat an integer group and a 3D array to be sure that I don't mess up the pointer math.  (I'm looking at this currently because the previous code had made inconsistent assignments to the memory).

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#define GROUPCOUNT 16
#define SENSORCOUNT 6
#define SENSORDIM   3
int main()
{
int *groupdata = (int *)calloc(GROUPCOUNT * SENSORCOUNT * SENSORDIM,sizeof(int));
int sensordata[SENSORCOUNT*SENSORDIM];
sensordata[7] = 42;  //assign some data 
int (*group3d)[GROUPCOUNT][SENSORCOUNT][SENSORDIM] = groupdata; //<---Here is the problem
group3d[1][5][1] = sensordata[7];  //I want to do this
free(groupdata);
}
```

In the example above, I want to handle `groupdata` as `group3d` temporarily for assignments, and I just cannot seem to wrap myself around the casting.  I currently have macros that do the pointer math to enforce the correct structure, but if it was all just in the code, it would be even better when I pass it off. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

**note:** The 3D cast is to be used in a function way in the bowels of the program.  The example is just a minimally viable program for me to try to sort out the code.

Comment: What exactly is the error ? Try using the caste. Why do you create a 3 dimensional array dynamically ? instead allocating memory to an `int *` ?

Comment: @Mazhar The array is allocated a `int *` but is passed around, and a function way in the depths would be served by a 3D cast.  The error, which makes sense, is `main.c:11:7: warning: incompatible pointer types initializing
      'int (*)[16][6][3]' with an expression of type 'int *'`

Comment: Yes, this is what's expected. You are assigning an `int (*)[16][6][3]` a simple `int *`.  Or more specifically, `group3d` has type `int (*)[16][6][3]` while `groupdata` has type `int *`. So you can't assign that directly. Though you can use the cast. In your case, if you allocate `group3d` directly as 3D array, you still can pass this single pointer to other functions just like you were passing the `groupdata` but this time you won't have to worry about the dimensions. Moreover, `group3d` is a single pointer with size of regular pointer. It is not any 3d array of pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `group3d` is defined with `int (*group3d)[GROUPCOUNT][SENSORCOUNT][SENSORDIM]`, then `*group3d` is a three-dimensional array. That would let you use it with `(*group3d)[1][5][1]`.

To use it with `group3d[1][5][1]`, you need `group3d` to be a pointer to a two-dimensional array:

```
int (*group3d)[SENSORCOUNT][SENSORDIM] = (int (*)[SENSORCOUNT][SENSORDIM]) groupdata;
```

(There are some technical concerns about C semantics in aliasing an array of `int` as an array of array of array of `int`, but this is not a problem in common compilers with default settings. However, it would be preferable to always use the memory as an array of array of array of `int`, not as an array of `int`.)

Comment: From your comments, it's probably better to just use my macros to do the pointer math then?  I was assuming that the compiler would be more reliable doing the mathematics.

Answer (score 1):

```
  int l = 5, w = 10, h = 15;
  int Data = 45;
  int *k = malloc(l * w * h * sizeof *k);
  // not use this k[a][b][c] = Data;
  //use this is right
   k[a*l*w + b*l + c] = Data;
```

Answer (score 0):

> In the example above, I want to handle groupdata as group3d
>   temporarily for assignments, and I just cannot seem to wrap myself
>   around the casting.

One possible solution is to create a multidimensional array dynamically like this. This way you won't have to cast things or worry about the dimensions.

```
int (*group3d)[GROUPCOUNT][SENSORCOUNT][SENSORDIM] = calloc(1, sizeof(int [GROUPCOUNT][SENSORCOUNT][SENSORDIM]));

(*group3d)[1][5][1] = sensordata[7];  //I want to do this

/* Then you can print it like */
printf("%d\r\n", (*group3d)[1][5][1]);
```

Comment: This will fail horribly—there will be no error message but `*group3d[1][5][1]` will access the wrong memory; it should be `(*group3d)[1][5][1]`. And it is not what the question requests; the question requests that access to an element be in the form `group3d[1][5][1]`, not `*group3d[1][5][1]` or `(*group3d)[1][5][1]`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the problem. Though I have checked that it is wokring.